# Redirecting to a new site unless in a specified directory

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I run an image hosting site. Lets just go with the following information.

```
Site: imagehosting.com
Tiny: imgho.st
Directory: n/
```

Directory is where the images are stored. Anyways. I'm trying to figure out an apache rewrite method to redirect imgho.st to imagehosting.com UNLESS in the n/ directory. So unless the user is imgho.st/n/83md.png redirect to imagehosting.com.

Could anybody help me out with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Also. I guess this belongs in ServerFault. Oops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put `RewriteCond` before your `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/n\/.*$
RewriteRule ...
```